# How to replace using sed command in shell scripting to replace a string from a txt file present in one directory by another?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am very new to shell scripting and trying to learn the "sed" command functionality.

I have a file called configurations.txt with some variables defined in it with some string values initialised to each of them. 
I am trying to replace a string in a file (values.txt) which is present in some other directory by the values of the variables defined. The name of the file is values.txt.

Data present in configurations.txt:-

```
mem="cpu.memory=4G"
proc="cpu.processor=Intel"
```

Data present in the values.txt (present in /home/cpu/script):-

```
cpu.memory=1G
cpu.processor=Dell
```

I am trying to make a shell script called repl.sh and I dont have alot of code in it for now but here is what I got:-

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/configurations.txt
sed <need some help here>
```

Expected output is after an appropriate regex applied, when I run script sh repl.sh, in my values.txt , It must have the following data present:-

```
cpu.memory=4G
cpu.processor=Intell
```

Originally which was 1G and Dell.

Would highly appreciate some quick help. Thanks

Comment: You should probably use `m4(1)` instead of `sed(1)`.  Better yet, learn some higher-level template system such as Template Toolkit or jinja.

Comment: Sorry mate but I have no idea about it. Can you please help?

Comment: Is it possible to drop `mem=` & `proc=` part? It would be easier using awk, without these parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question lacks some sort of abstract routine and looks like "help me do something concrete please". Thus it's very unlikely that anyone would provide a full solution for that problem.

What you should do try to split this task into number of small pieces.

1) Iterate over `configuration.txt` and get values from each line. To do that you need to get `X` and `Y` from a `value="X=Y"` string.

This regex could be helpful here - `([^=]+)=\"([^=]+)=([^=]+)\"`. It contains 3 matching groups separated by `"`. For example,

```
>> sed -r 's/([^=]+)=\"([^=]+)=([^=]+)\"/\1/' configurations.txt
mem
proc
>> sed -r 's/([^=]+)=\"([^=]+)=([^=]+)\"/\2/' configurations.txt
cpu.memory
cpu.processor
>> sed -r 's/([^=]+)=\"([^=]+)=([^=]+)\"/\3/' configurations.txt
4G
Intel
```

2) For each `X` and `Y` find `X=Z` in `values.txt` and substitute it with a `X=Y`.

For example, let's change `cpu.memory` value in `values.txt` with `4G`:

```
>> X=cpu.memory; Y=4G; sed -r "s/(${X}=).*/\1${Y}/" values.txt
cpu.memory=4G
cpu.processor=Dell
```

Use `-i` flag to do changes in place.

Comment: Thanks alot! This is easy to understand and nice explained. But can you please help me that how can I get the new values saved in values.txt? So that next I open values.txt, I see the new replaced values.

Comment: It gives an error saying sed: -e expression #1, char 23: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS when i use sed -i

Comment: `sed -i -r "s/(${X}=).*/\1${Y}/" values.txt` works for me, sed version is `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` based answer:

```
$ cat config.txt
cpu.memory=4G
cpu.processor=Intel

$ cat values.txt
cpu.memory=1G
cpu.processor=Dell
cpu.speed=4GHz

$ awk -F= 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next;}; {if($1 in a){$2=a[$1]}}1' OFS== config.txt values.txt 
cpu.memory=4G
cpu.processor=Intel
cpu.speed=4GHz
```

Explanation: First read config.txt & save in memory. Then read values.txt. If a particular value was defined in config.txt, use the saved value from memory (config.txt).

Comment: It does print but doesnt replaces anything in values.txt  @anishsane

Comment: & is it difficult to send the output to a file & overwrite the old file?
`command > tmpfile && mv tmpfile values.txt`